# Error propagation for a constant divided by the value

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis, statistics

I have a value (let's just call it $x$) and am given its uncertainty. However, **how would I find the uncertainty of $2/x$**? I know that for other constants, if it was something like x/2 or 2x I would multiply/divide the percent uncertainty, but how would I go about this if the constant was in the numerator (would it be 2/% uncertainty)?

Answer (score 1):

one way is with the propagation of errors formula.

For a measurement $R$ that depends on $n$ independent variables $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$, each with uncertainties $\Delta x_1, \Delta x_2, \dots, \Delta x_n$, the error on $R$ is given as $$\Delta R = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \bigg( \dfrac{\partial R}{\partial x_i}\Delta x_i\bigg)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The fractional uncertainty on a number raised to some power is the power times the original fractional uncertainty. That is,

$$
\big(
x\cdot(1\pm\delta)
\big)^n
≈
x^n\cdot(1\pm n\delta)
$$

where $\delta\ll 1$ is the dimensionless fractional uncertainty on $x$.  For example, if you believe $x$ is between 1.02 and 1.04 (i.e. a 1% uncertainty), then $1/x$ will lie between 0.96 and 0.98 (also a 1% uncertainty).